# Error when executing : dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli,Unable to find git in your PATH

Tags: flutter, dart

please , When I execute this commande dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli

i have this message :Error: Unable to find git in your PATH.

I thought the PATH would PATH, but it didn't
Google login is now available.I don't know what to do next.
please tell me.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to install firebase_core `flutter pub add firebase_core`.
Check out documentation here [FlutterFire Overview](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview/)

Answer (score 0):

Step one: Run $ dart fix --dry-run

Step two: Run $ dart fix --apply

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).